# Error with alert view and game centre options

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I am making and application and have come across an error with this code:

```
NSString *timemessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unlucky! You survived for %i seconds!", timenumber];
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You've Been Caught!" message:timemessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Show Leaderboard", @"Submit To Game Center",nil];
[alert1 show];

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)ButtonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:ButtonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Submit To Game Center"]) {
        - (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category
        {
            GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"*****"] autorelease];
            scoreReporter.value = score;
            [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil)
                {
                    // handle the reporting error
                }
            }];
        }
    }
    else if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Show Leaderboard"]){
        - (void) showLeaderboard:
        {
            GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
            if (leaderboardController != nil)
            {
                leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
                [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So the problems I'm facing are:

1. The buttons do not work with the alert, they simply do nothing.
2. There is an error "Invalid argument type "void" to unary expression"

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that the first issue is on the alert delegate.

```
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You've Been Caught!" message:timemessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Show Leaderboard", @"Submit To Game Center",nil];
[alert1 show];
```

See the **delegate:self**